# Gems return bad interpreter path error

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I had installed ruby using homebrew but uninstalled recently. Whever I exectue a gem (any gem) it returns following error on OS X Yosemite. How do I solve it?

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/cap: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.3/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've removed Homebrew you might want to remove `/usr/local` as well. There may be binaries in that structure that are still lingering in your path, especially if you've installed Homebrew Ruby.

Check that your `$PATH` is up to date.

Comment: I did not uninstall Homebrew, rather uninstalled Ruby which I installed using Homebrew. Gem's local installation path seems /usr/local/bin how do we change this?

Comment: You may have lingering "binstubs" in that directory you need to remove. This is where a tool like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) is much better at containing that mess than the Homebrew stock Ruby. As you find them, delete them.

Comment: You're right. /usr/local/bin had some dirty references.